# importing tkinter in Abaqus error

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, abaqus

I have a problem durring abaqus scripting. I am trying to use tkinter in an abaqus scipt. When I run my code for the first time the program runs fine but when I run my program the second time, then the abaqus quits with the following error:
"Unexpected LoadlibraryA error 193
ipc_CONNECTION_BROKEN"

I'm using abaqus 6.14 with python 2.7
running with Intel Paralllal Stuido XE 2015 Composer Edition 64 bit Update 2

My plugin class looks like this:

```
from abaqusGui import getAFXApp, Activator
from abaqusConstants import ALL
import os
thisPath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
thisDir = os.path.dirname(thisPath)
toolset = getAFXApp().getAFXMainWindow().getPluginToolset()
toolset.registerGuiMenuButton(
    buttonText='Pilot GUI', 
    object= Activator(os.path.join(thisDir, 'pilotDB.py')),
    kernelInitString=''
)
```

my pilotDB class looks like this:

```
class pilotDB:     
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = pilotDB(root)
root.mainloop()
root.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:
The problem was when I first closed the TK window with the X on the upper right corner, the application cannot destroyed the window properly so when I started app the second time, it crashed. Solution:
Add the following code to my pilotDB class:

```
def shutdown_ttk_repeat(self):
     self.mainroot.eval('::ttk::CancelRepeat')
     self.mainroot.destroy()
```

and then add the destroying protokol to the start of "**init**" function in pilotDB class

```
def __init__(self, parent):
     self.mainroot=parent
     self.mainroot.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.shutdown_ttk_repeat):
```